# Delete unwanted Columns and add some text to 1st column of a csv

Tags: csv, vb6

I have a *csv* file.There are many columns like *"Commodity"* , *"Ex-basis delivery centre"*, *"Price unit"* etc I don't want and I want to delete. How can this be done

Also I want to add `1,2,3` such numbers as per expiry to the first column. Example:

```
SYMBOL     EXPIRY
BARLEYJPR  8/17/2012
BARLEYJPR  9/20/2012
BARLEYJPR  10/19/2012
BARLEYJPR  11/20/2012
```

In first line I would like to add 1 to `BARLEYJPR` as the expiry is on `august 17th 2012(8/17/2012)` which is nearest of all then would like to add 2 to `BARLEYJPR` as expiry is in `September` then would like to add 3 to `BARLEYJPR` as expiry is in `October` and lastly 4 to `BARLEYJPR` as expiry is in `November`.

Can someone help me? I'M LOOKING FOR CODE IN ***VB6*** AS I HAVE ALREADY WRITTEN CODE IN ***VB6*** TO DOWNLOAD FILES FROM THE WEBSITE.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo Err
Const q As String = "-"
Dim tmp As String, fName As String, Pos As Long, fPath As String
Dim first As Date, last As Date, spath As String, d As Date
cap = Me.Caption
If Dir(App.Path & "\NCDEX\") = "" Then
    MkDir App.Path & "\NCDEX\"
End If
spath = App.Path & "\NCDEX\" ' folder to save files : note trailing \
first = MonthView1
last = MonthView2
'http://www.ncdex.com/Downloads/Bhavcopy_Summary_File/Export_csv/07-04-2012.csv
strURL = "http://www.ncdex.com/Downloads/Bhavcopy_Summary_File/Export_csv/"
    For d = first To last
    ssourceurl = strURL & Format(d, "MM") & q & Format(d, "dd") & q & Format(d, "yyyy") & ".csv"
    fName = Format(d, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".csv"
    slocalfile = spath & fName
    Me.Caption = "Downloading  " & fName
    Call DeleteUrlCacheEntry(ssourceurl)
    URLDownloadToFile 0&, ssourceurl, slocalfile, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&
    Debug.Print ssourceurl
Next
Me.Caption = cap
'YOU CAN TAKE THIS BELOW OUT IF U DONT WANT IT
MsgBox "Saved to " & spath, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success!"
Exit Sub
Err:     MsgBox "Error", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Market Was Closed"
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph, nor your example. As for deleting columns - just read in the data, and then write it out again, not outputting the column you want to delete.

Comment: Your code sample does not relate to your question. Post the code that you already have to do with removing the columns from the CSV file once you have downloaded it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here relate to a _specific programming problem_. Simply making a list of requirements (like placing an order) is frowned upon. Please show what code you are using to delete columns and specifically where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the Jet engine to read the CSV file to a recordset and manipulate it like you do with a database using ADO.

Some examples and reference sites:

- http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2180
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26822/Read-Text-File-txt-csv-log-tab-fixed-length
- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=674758